# Does $\frac{|x_{i+1}-x_n|}{|x_i-x_n|}< 1$ implies convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence ${x_i}$

If somehow we can derive $\frac{|x_{i+1}-x_n|}{|x_i-x_n|}< 1$ for all $n > {i+1}$

Does this directly implies convergence?

If yes, how about the case including equal signs?

$\frac{|x_{i+1}-x_n|}{|x_i-x_n|} \leq 1$

Comment: Is the $i$ in that fraction fixed, or is the relation supposed to hold for all $i$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $x_{n}=-n$. Counterexample for both cases.